# Centering a position absolute img with a position relative img

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**Hi!**

I have 2 images, one with position absolute (the background) and one with position relative, I want to center the position relative one to the position absolute one. I tried a lot of methods, with margin auto, transform, and others but nothing works for me.

[image: problem]

Here's my code (I'm using React.js):

```
import './information.css'

import Background from '../../assets/character_informations_bg.png'

export default function Information(props) {
  return (
    <div className="character-information">
        <div>
            <img src={Background} alt="" className='character-information-bg' />
            <img src={props.image} alt="" className='character-information-clothes' />
        </div>
        <p>{props.name}<br />{props.price}</p>
    </div>
  )
}

// CSS (information.css)
.character-information-bg {
    position: absolute;
}
.character-information-clothes {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 90px;
    max-height: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `left` and `top` properties on `.character-information-clothes`

example -

```
.character-information-clothes {
  position: relative;
  left: 20%;
  top: 20rem;
  max-width: 90px;
  max-height: 90px;
}
```

adjust `top` and `left` according to yours background possitioning

Comment: I use different images and If I use `left: 20%` some images are centered (the pants) and some are not (the shirt).

Comment: @Yonut you should adjust those values according to yours `left` & `top`

Comment: I adjusted them but not all images have the same width and height so the `left` and `top` are good for all of them.

Comment: @Yonut do u want to center the image in the background in all?

Comment: Yeah, If that's possible, If not, I have an idea and I'll try it

Comment: @Yonut here https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-rubin-4i540q working example ,